# react native apply styles to all Text Components

Tags: react-native

Is there an easy way to apply styles to all components of a specific type such as `Text` or `ScrollView` etc in react native to build templates? 
For example, I wish to use `verdana` `fontFamily` style to all Text components across all scenes. Is there an easy way to achieve than specifying the style everytime I use Text component? 
Or does it require creating a custom Text component? and use it instead of the basic component such as below example. Use `MyText` instead of `Text`

```
const MyText = ({data}) => <Text style={style.commonTextStyle}>{data}</Text>
```

Answer (score 15):

In addition to Vicky's answer, you can simply create a new Component with name Text or MyText etc, and import it to your project whenever you need it.

```
function MyText(props) {
  return (
    <Text style={styles.MY_CUSTOM_STYLES}>
      {props.children}
    </Text>
  );
}
```

And use it like,

```
import MyText from '/path/to/MyText';

...

render() {
  return ( <MyText>Now I have my custom styles.</MyText> );
}
```

You can use it as import Text by changing its name if you feel so used to defining Text components. Refer to [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#extracting-components) for further reading. *(Note that: MyText Component above is a [functional stateless component](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) for lightweight definitions.)*

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props seems to offer global styles for most of the react native components including Text, View etc. Readme from the GitHub has examples. This appears to address the need however I have not tested this yet.

Answer (score 5):

You must create a RN Component like this:

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text as TextRN } from 'react-native';

export default class Text extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextRN style={[YOUR_CUSTOM_STYLES, this.props.style]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </TextRN>
    )
  }
}
```

In this way, your own Text component can inheritance additional styles from anywhere you use them.

**Note:** Have in mind that your own custom text component can't be used in all cases, e.g. inside TouchableHighlight, in these case you must be use the native text from react-native library.

Now, you just can change your imports for:

```
import Text from 'YOUR_PATH/Text.js'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: onPress doesn't work on <Text> after the above implementation. So it should be wrapped with <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._rM} underlayColor="transparent">

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the common styles and provide them as global. you can them add/ edit the styles for each textview if needed.

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
})
```

Then u can use `<Text style={[styles.welcome, {color:'red'}]]}>Hello</Text>`

U should look into libs like [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet)

You can also follow these techniques on how to keep the stylesheet simple and readble.
Refer [Tips for styling React](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/tips-for-styling-your-react-native-apps-3f61608655eb#.ylsj93hgt)

Comment: This wont help with my ask. Every user needs to make sure to provide the correct styles across entire codebase when Text component is used. I was asking for a generic solution such as providing css in HTML for a specific tag. It seems the only solution is to create a custom component such as MyText as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @sumanj can you accept my answer or enter one yourself to mark this question and help others who face the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

In your *Global-Styles* js file:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Text as RNText
} from "react-native";

const styles = {
  text: {
    lineHeight: "1.5em",
    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    marginVertical: "0.2em",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
}

export var Text = (props) => <RNText style={[styles.text, props.style]}>{props.children}</RNText>
```

Usage (Same as normal Text):

```
import {Text} from './StyledComponents'

...
<Text style={{marginTop: '20px', color: 'red'}}>Hello, World!</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new component and apply any modification you want in it.

```
class MyText extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Text {...this.props}
                     style={[this.props.style, style.commonTextStyle]}>{this.props.children}</Text>;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add {...this.props}. this way you pass all props to the new component you are defining.

Answer (score 0):

[Glamorous](https://github.com/paypal/glamorous) also handles this very cleanly in React Native:

```
const MyText = glamorous.Text({
  // ... any styles
});

export MyText;
```