# React native, system font size

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-size

In my App when I change the system font size it changes the app's font size as well, what can I do to prevent going too higher value. ex :

```
system font size: 1 -> font-size: 10px  
system font size: 2 -> font-size: 14px
system font size: 3 -> font-size: 18px
system font size: 4 -> font-size: 18px
system font size: 5 -> font-size: 18px
```

Comment: Whatever answers you get, I strongly recommend ***not*** doing this as it is an accessibility concern.  If a user wants bigger fonts, they should be able to have bigger fonts despite your design.  This mean people with vision impairments are still able to use your app by scaling up font.

Comment: I agree with @zero298 but to answer your question, you can use the `maxFontSizeMultiplier` prop of Text https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#maxfontsizemultiplier

Comment: @UğurEren is there a way to set a default value in the hole project ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, however you can create your own Text component and use that in your project. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084099/5793132